# Ubuntu remove minimize and maximize buttons

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

I use double click to maximize a window, and middle click to minimize a window. the actual minimize and maximize buttons have become useless. I would like to remove these buttons. I heard that you can make a theme to do this, but I don't know how. I'm guessing it's somewhere in the xml file within the metacity folder inside the theme, but that file is huge, and I don't know if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do this command in terminal to change them:

> [Move Window Buttons in Ubuntu 12.04/12.10](http://handytutorial.com/move-window-buttons-to-right-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/)
>
> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close:'

If you want to further change the layout, or move them - the ":" specifies which side of the window the max/min/close are on.  You can also change the layout of which is where with 'close,maximize,minimize:' or any variation therein.

(You only need user rights and it is persistent.)

Comment: thanks! it worked. however, when it is maximized, it still shows all 3 buttons. this is probably due to the way unity works. is their a way to configure it so when it is maximized, it only shows one button?

Comment: Looks like it's built into the Unity shell whereas the others are metacity.  Unity is a compiz plugin essentially and ignores the metacity keys.  So far, no luck.  I will look around this evening

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not look terribly promising.  Hopefully soon for you!